# Add a reuired field to document being stored in a doc library

Tags: document, soap

I'm not at all sure this can even be done, I certainly can't find an example anywhere.....

I have a document library of a bunch of internal documents our company uses. I have a CEWP that searches the library and prints out the name and hyperlinks to these (word) docs. This is all done dynamically. However.......

I don't really want to hardcode anything, but I can't figure out one thing. When I edit a document, the only fields that SP asks for are 'Name' and 'Title'. I would also like to have it so the user needs to input a description (if they decide to add a new document to our doc library). Then, I can print to screen the title with the hyperlink, but also have a description of the document listed underneath. Obviously this is easy to hard code, but I really would love to have it dynamically generated.

I have no access to SP designer, I am forced to do this all through CEWPs.

Do any of you clever Bettys know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a content type that includes any information you need, like a description column.  Apply this content type to your document library.  Then when a new file is uploaded, users will be taken to the EditPage where this information can be entered.  If a new item is created through the library new button, then the columns will appear in the document information panel.

Then using your CEWP code and modifying it to include this description field, you can display all the data needed to the users.